# JavaScript array has a 3rd party prototype which causes trouble, how can I revert to normal behavior?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm resolving a JS conflict in my WP plugin on a site. When I create an empty array using

```
var myArray = [];
```

or

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

the `console.log(myArray);` says this:

```
[randomize: function]
```

instead of

```
[]
```

The length of the array remains 0. The randomize function's placement can be seen here: http://postimage.org/image/j67yqby5t/ In chrome I clicked 'Show function definition' and it's added by a WP plugin called LayerSlider.

```
    Array.prototype.randomize = function () {
    var e = this.length,
        t, n, r;
    if (e == 0) return false;
    while (--e) {
        t = Math.floor(Math.random() * (e + 1));
        n = this[e];
        r = this[t];
        this[e] = r;
        this[t] = n
    }
    return this
};
```

What should I do to (perhaps temporarily) revert it to a normal, empty array? Or just to remove every non native elements from an array?

By the way the problem came up when I iterated through it with

```
for(var i in myArray ){ ... }
```

and it treated the function as an extra element. I had numerically indexed elements added to it by the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule is that if you only want to iterate over the numeric properties of an array (i.e. the indexes), use a for, do or while loop with a counter.

If you use for..in, then you should include a [`hasOwnProperty`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5) test to avoid iterating over named properties inherited through the `[[Prototype]]` chain.

```
for (var p in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    // p isn't inherited, do stuff with obj[p]
  }
}
```

Lastly, you can probably delete the method from Array.prototype using the `delete` operator, but likely a library you've loaded is using it.

Comment: I actually managed to delete it and put it back (by storing it in a temporary var). But I can't do this for every random prototype that can occur in the future, aside from this example. So your solution is very clear, thank you very much! I'll improve my code.

Comment: I was going to suggest delete then return it, but that's pretty awful. There are good reasons to use for..in with an array, but generally an index loop is preferred.

Comment: Solved it with this in the end: `for (var i = 0, j = myArray.length; i < j; i += 1) {  
    // do some stuff here  
}` according to http://www.impressivewebs.com/javascript-for-loop/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do nothing if wordpress plugins override the native array of javascript.
They can do it by binding function to the prototype of the array:

```
Array.prototype.randomise = function(){
    //some code...
};
```

If it's index array you can make for(var i=0.. loops and if it's hashmap you can ask whether and item is a function using typeof:

```
for(var val in arr){
    if(typeof(arr[val]) != 'function'){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing against a function is flawed. You should use `hasOwnProperty` as RobG suggests in his answer. You can also change `for(i in arr)` to `for(var i=0,e=arr.length;i<e;++i)` which has the same result